# How to get navigation links in a row

Tags: html

I'm trying to figure out how to get my links in a row at the top of my screen. For some reason the method I'm using doesn't make that happen. What am I doing wrong?

```
<td>
    <FORM METHOD="LINK" ACTION="www1.skysports.com/football/teams/realmadrid/…; <INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Fixtures & Updates"></FORM>
</td>
```

Comment: And where is the method you are using?

Comment: You should be more specific in your question. Show us what you tried. In any case, I'm almost sure you can solve it by setting `display: inline-block`.

Comment: Some code please. If possible create a fiddle JSfiddle.net

Comment: <td><FORM METHOD="LINK" ACTION="http://www1.skysports.com/football/teams/realmadrid/fixtures-results">
<INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Fixtures & Updates"></FORM></td>

Comment: I don't know whats actually wrong with it :/

Comment: Edit your question, to insert the code you set here in the comments

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/u3z3g/1/

```
<nav>
    <a href="/">Home</a>
    <a href="/mypage">My Page</a>
    <a href="/myotherpage">My other Page</a>
</nav>
```

No need for tables or forms. Tables are for tables, forms are for forms. Not navigation.

Since you want to have the links look like buttons, you should give them a background and border-radius.

```
nav a {
    padding: 4px 8px;
    background: #ddd;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
nav a:hover {
    background: #eee;
}
nav a:active {
    background: #ccc;
}
```

Of course, modify the CSS to your liking.

Comment: I need them to be buttons

Comment: You can style them with CSS to look like buttons.